# How to prove this property of sawtooth wave

Tags: analysis

I'm reading Emil Artin's short book [The Gamma Function](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Artin%20E.%20The%20Gamma%20Function%20(1931)(23s).pdf).

Since page 29 he says,

Define $H(t) = \frac12 - t$ for $0<t<1$, $H(0)=0$ for $t=0$, and otherwise periodic of period 1. Then he introduces

$$H_{2n}(t):=2(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\cos 2i\pi t}{(2i\pi)^{2n}}$$
$$H_{2n-1}(t):=2(-1)^{n}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\sin 2i\pi t}{(2i\pi)^{2n-1}}$$, 
then one can see $$-H_1(t)=H(t)$$ because $-H_1(t)$ is the Fourier series for $H(t)$ and $$H'_{n+1}(t)=H_n(t)$$ for $n\ge 2$ or $n=1$ for all non-integral $x$.

Till here all are good.

Then he says: if $n$ is even, $H_n(0)-H_n(t)$ has the same sign (plus or miuns) as $H_n(0)$ for all $t$.

I wonder how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|H_{2n}(t)|\le 2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\cos(2i\pi t)|}{(2i\pi)^{2n}}\le 2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2i\pi)^{2n}}=|H_{2n}(0)|$$

As $\forall t ||H_{2n}||_\infty\pm H_{2n}(t) \ge 0$ it follows the expected result i.e. $H_{2n}(0)-H_{2n}(t)$ has the same sign as $H_{2n}(0)$

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it.